# Rotated div not sticking to the right border of the viewport (flats to the left)

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

So I'm trying to align this absolutely positioned red div with text completely to the right, I'm using transform and rotate in order to flip the div but in the proccess the div stays floating rght next to the right border of the viewport, I want to be completely aligned to the right border instead.

How could I aproach this with css?

```css
body{position:relative;}
```

```html
<div style="padding:15px 125px 15px 15px; background-color:red; display:flex; align-items:center; z-index:999999999999999;  position:absolute; right:0px; top:40%; transform: rotate(-90deg); transform-origin:center;">
    <i class="fa fa-cutlery" style="color:black; font-size:20px; margin-right:10px;"></i>
 <span style="font-size:30px; color:black;">Reservar</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may adjust the code like this:

```html
<div style="padding:15px 125px 15px 15px; background-color:red; display:flex; align-items:center; z-index:999999999999999;  position:absolute; right:0px; top:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);transform-origin:top right;">
    <i class="fa fa-cutlery" style="color:black; font-size:20px; margin-right:10px;"></i>
 <span style="font-size:30px; color:black;">Reservar</span>
</div>
```